# Highcharts Chart Bar - How can I display in the chart, only one column from my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I got a Bar Chart that extract its data from a HTML table in the page.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

How can I extract only one column of the table, if we follow the example above, the **John** comlumn...

This is the code that builds the serias

```
// the categories
options.xAxis.categories = [];
$('tbody th', table).each( function(i) {
    options.xAxis.categories.push(this.innerHTML);
});

// the data series
options.series = [];
$('tr', table).each( function(i) {
    var tr = this;
    $('th, td', tr).each( function(j) {
        if (j > 0) { // skip first column
            if (i == 0) { // get the name and init the series
                options.series[j - 1] = {
                    name: this.innerHTML,
                    data: []
                };
            } else { // add values
                options.series[j - 1].data.push(parseFloat(this.innerHTML));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried to read only the columns that are equal to 2, in order to reach the last one, and didn't succeed

```
if (j == 2) { ... }
```

Hope anyone will have better answers than me.
Shlomi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
options.series = [];
$('tr', table).each( function(i) {
    var tr = this;
    $('th, td', tr).each( function(j) {
        if (j == 2) { // get only column 2
            if (i == 0) { // get the name and init the series
                options.series[0] = {
                    name: this.innerHTML,
                    data: []
                };
            } else { // add values
                options.series[0].data.push(parseFloat(this.innerHTML));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You need to check that `j == 2` so that you only get the data in the 2nd column and then when you create the `options.series` array you need to use `0` - Highcharts expects at least data in `series[0]`

[Working Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTSEX/)